# Autofac IOC - RegisterAssemblyTypes vs RegisterType

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I implemented AutoFac after gone through the documentation in my `webapi2` application. Have the services in different assembly of the project. To resolve the dependencies, i tried below three ways which all worked independently. Though it works, i sense each has its own usage to implement. How each handles my dependency and where that to be used?

```
builder.RegisterType<TestManager>().AsImplementedInterfaces();//first way  
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(TestManager).Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();//second way  
builder.RegisterType<TestManager>().As<ITestManager>();//third way
```

Comment: Did you read the Autofac documentation, and what did you find out after reading the documentation?

Comment: @Steven `AsImplementedInterfaces` scans the assembly and resolve all public services. `builder.RegisterType<TestManager>().As<ITestManager>()` resolves the dependency like one to one. If I have 10 concrete classes, i feel odd to do one to one registration. This is my understanding

Answer (score 4):

Each one of those three ways has its pros and cons. No one is better or worse, it depends on the specific scenario where you are going to apply them.

**First way:** explicit register of the type, with implicit interfaces.

```
builder.RegisterType<TestManager>().AsImplementedInterfaces();//first way
```

Pros:

- If you modify your type to implement a new interface you don't have to add anything to the autofac register, it will be automatically registered. So: reduced maintenance compared to (3) because interfaces are implicit.
- Explicit registration of the type gives you fine-grained control over registrations. You can ignore types that will not be used in your client application, and only register the ones you need. This is an advantage compared to (2).

Cons:

- You still have to explicitly register your types and update your autofac code when you add/remove types (not when you add/remove interfaces). So: increased maintenance compared to (2) because you have to register each type.
- You can have unexpected side effects if you modify your type to implement a new interface, because without adding anything to the autofac register, it will be automatically registered.

**Second way:** register all types in the assembly without specifically enumerating types or interfaces.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(TestManager).Assembly)
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();//second way
```

Pros:

- Well suited for simple applications.
- Very handy if you have mostly simple registrations and don't want to do many configurations in the autofac modules.
- You don't have to add anything to the autofac configuration when adding/removing types or interfaces in your assembly.
- The main benefit with this approach is a very reduced autofac maintenance compared to the other two ways.

Cons:

- Frequent side effects when you add/remove types to your assembly, as they get automatically registered.
- Gets more problematic if you register components from several assemblies using this approach.
- Less transparent: Difficult to know if one component is registered or not just by looking at the autofac code.
- You can end up registering things twice, with different configurations. And remember that the order in registration does matter.
- Perhaps you are registering lots of unneeded types. Every public type in the assembly gets registered. If your assembly is very big, or you are only going to use a subset of its types then this approach may not be the best.

**Third way:** explicit registration of the type, with explicit interfaces.

```
builder.RegisterType<TestManager>().As<ITestManager>();//third way
```

Pros:

- Better control if your type implement several interfaces.
- Usually better suited if you need to do more complex registrations in your autofac code.
- Avoids side effects when adding/removing types or interfaces in your code, as unless you explicitly modify your autofac code they will not be applied.
- So: the best control of the three approaches, and better suited for complex autofac registrations.

Cons:

- You need to explicitly register every type.
- This approach requires more maintenance of the autofac code. Usually you have to change it when you change the types/interfaces in your code. So: biggest autofac code maintenance of the three ways.

There are for sure more pros/cons that the ones I enumerated. These were the ones that come to mind to me. I think they can be a good starting point for you. You will learn which one you prefer by using them in real scenarios.

You will probably use some combination of the three ways. A common approach is to use (2) in simple scenarios, and add specific registrations with (1) or (3) for types that require more complex registrations. If your registration needs are not that simple or you application is very big I wouldn't recommend using (2), as it can be difficult to know what are you really registering.
And remember that the order of the registrations does matter. They are cummulative, and the last one wins. So if you are going to use (2) combined with (1) or (3) you should do first (2) and then the other ones (otherwise the specific registrations will be overwritten by the general ones).